# In swift, how do I make layers of a view programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, I have a view with three objects. I want the button and label to be on top of the image. This is a concept like maybe layers in Photoshop. Currently, the image is on top of the button and label, so you can not see the button and label. How is this done?

**My code is here:**

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            let myFirstLabel = UILabel()
            let myFirstButton = UIButton()
            let myFirstImage = UIImage(named: "1792614.jpg")
            let myFirstImageView = UIImageView(image: myFirstImage)

            myFirstLabel.text = "I made a label on the screen #toogood4you"
            myFirstLabel.font = UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Thin", size: 45)
            myFirstLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            myFirstLabel.textAlignment = .Center
            myFirstLabel.numberOfLines = 5
            myFirstLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 54, 300, 500)

            myFirstButton.setTitle("✸", forState: .Normal)
            myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
            myFirstButton.frame = CGRectMake(160, 284, 50, 50)
            myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            self.view.addSubview(myFirstLabel)
            self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
            self.view.addSubview(myFirstImageView)
        }

        func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
            var alertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alertView.title = "title"
            alertView.message = "message"
            alertView.show()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is here:

```
self.view.addSubview(myFirstLabel)
self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
self.view.addSubview(myFirstImageView)
```

When you add a subview, it always gets put at the top, to achieve what you want, add the view you want at the bottom first, and the one you want on top last:

```
self.view.addSubview(myFirstImageView)
self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
self.view.addSubview(myFirstLabel)
```

Comment: Okay. Yeah, that works. I will make your answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the views in this order:

```
self.view.addSubview(myFirstLabel)
self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
self.view.addSubview(myFirstImageView)
```

which means `myFirstImageView` is going to be on top. Reversing the order of the `addSubview` calls will do what you want.